# How to simply read response from POST request via HttpClient?

Tags: angular, httpclient

In my Service class I have variable a called `token` and I want to assign a value to it when a function is called. Let's suppose there is a method called login and it should only return the response from the containing post request:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, {email: email, password: password})
          .pipe(
            catchError(error => of(error))
          );
}
```

The function could look something like that. Within it I now try to assign the value from the Response to `this.token`.

How I could solve this problem?

Comment: *What* problem? What have you tried? Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the response and set `this.token` using this code:

```js
/* 
Your user model can be like this: 
interface User {
  token: string;
}
*/
this.httpClient.post(url, {email: email, password: password}).pipe(
      tap(async (userInfo: User) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (userInfo) {                    
          this.token = userInfo.token;
        }
        return userInfo;
      })
    );
```

You can also specify the type of model which are expecting as response like this:

```js
this.httpClient.post<User>(url, {email: email, password: password})
```

**Here how you can use it in your code:**

```js
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, {email: email, password: password}).pipe(
      tap(async (response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (response) {                    
          this.token = response.token;
        }
        return response;
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: token won't be defined until something `subscribe()` s the observable returned by `login()`

Answer (score 1):

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, {email: email, password: password}).subscribe(data => {
        this.token = data.token;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use RXJS, make everything simpler.

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

private loginService(url, data) {
        try {
          return this._http.post(
            Url,
            data,
            this.httpOptions
          );
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
```

The httpClient already returns an observable so no need to declare it.
Then you just subscribe to it:

```
    this.loginService(url, {email: email, password: password}).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            console.log('Login info');
          },
          (error) => console.log(error),
          () => {
            console.log('Complete);
          },
        );
```